# What does 4: mean in g++ apt-get install version string?

Tags: installation, g++, version, apt-get

On EasyPeasy 1.1 (for mini notebooks) derived from Ubuntu I installed g++ using apt-get:

```
$ apt-get install g++
```

One of the lines displayed was:

```
Setting up g++ (4:4.3.1-1ubuntu2) ...
```

What the does "4:" mean?

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.3.2-1ubuntu12) 4.3.2
```

What is the relationship of the "4.3.1" in apt-get to the "4.3.2" g++ version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [epoch](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version).  According to the debian policy manual,

> the purpose of epochs is to allow us
>   to leave behind mistakes in version
>   numbering, and to cope with situations
>   where the version numbering scheme
>   changes

IIRC gcc 3.4.x introduced ABI-incompatible changes from the 3.3.x series, and this epoch may have been introduced by debian maintainers at that time.